# Expansion of some singular kernel with the help of Bessel and Neumann spherical harmonic functions

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials, singular-integrals

With the following notations:

- $j_n$: spherical Bessel functions,
- $y_n$: spherical Neumann function,
- $P_n$: Legendre polynomial,
- $r$, $\rho$, $\theta$, $\lambda$ arbitrary complex,
  $R=\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos\theta},$

I want a justification of those two expansions:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(\lambda R)}{\lambda R}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)\,j_n(\lambda R)\,j_n(\lambda \rho)\,P_n(\cos\theta),\\
-\frac{\cos(\lambda R)}{\lambda R}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)\,j_n(\lambda R)\,y_n(\lambda \rho)\,P_n(\cos\theta)
\end{align}
with $|r e^{\pm i\theta}|<|\rho|$.